# How to make Enter cmd command without suffix

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I encountered a strange problem in the windows environment, when I open cmd command window and enter inside php, results suggest that I can not find this command, but when I type php.exe is good, why is this so? I have php added to the PATH, which is a setting not windows10 is caused by incorrect, I can remember before, it will not be automatically upgraded influence?

Comment: Given the accepted answer, it looks like someone mistakenly ran `set PATHEXT=PATHEXT;.PY;.PYM` instead of the correct `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PY;.PYM` (note the `%`) when attempting to add `.PY` and `.PYM` to the list of executable extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to launch Run.

Type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Click Environment Variables

Double-click `PATHEXT`

Make sure `.EXE` is included there. It should look like.

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: I follow your guidance to find the problem, because the original is in the user environment variable is a software add something, I should be installed automatically when you install python.    `PATHEXT=PATHEXT;.PY;.PYM`

Comment: I am now able to do is put things in user variables are automatically added to remove, so after I tested the problem has been solved.